# ng-repeat with angular datatable plugin

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-datatables

I have been trying out ng-repeat option with angular datatable plugin (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables). But I have been getting a loading symbol. I tried my code in jsfiddle - (http://jsfiddle.net/pmspraju/ckuqkmqe/).
Controller:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['datatables']);
myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list1 = [{
        "id": "1",
        "value": "angular"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "value": "meteor"
    }];

});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <label>list: {{list1}}</label>
    <table datatable="ng" style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-model="list">
            <tr ng-repeat="lang in list1" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
                <td>{{lang.id}}</td>
                <td>{{lang.value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">

</script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">

</script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-datatablesjs-site.orionhub.org:8000/angular-datatables.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-datatablesminjs-site.orionhub.org:8000/angular-datatables.min.js">

</script>
```

If possible please help me out. I would appreciate any input (as I am new to angular). Please let me know, if i need to add anything in my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your fiddle does not work, but if I paste your markup into a plnkr it works right away -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/f1Lr13mj38ZOZ7Hh1iUp?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for your response @davidkonrad. I think some of my paths to scripts are wrong. I have created another fiddle by referring to above plunker. it works. Thanks again. http://jsfiddle.net/pmspraju/f4tpmq93/